# Block special prompt during add new file system

Tags: redhat

I try to create a new file system for my sftp server, but when I run the command it prompts something about a `block special device` that I don't understand.

I tried to mount using following command :

```
mkfs.ext4 /MYPJsftpfs
```

to create the new file system.

> [root@mykulsftp01 ~]# mkfs.ext4 /MYPJsftpfs
>   mke2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
>   /MYPJsftpfs is not a block special device.
>   Proceed anyway? (y,n)

What actually is a `block special device`? Why on other server did I not get this prompt when creating a new file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i tried to mount using below command :
>   `mkfs.ext4 /MYPJsftpfs`

Note, please, this command is not for mount !
With it you try to build ext4 file system on some block device.

from `man mkfs`:

> `mkfs`  is  used  to  build  a  Linux  file  system **on a device, usually a hard disk partition**.

You wrote:

> What is actually special block device?

A block device is a kind of file which represents a device of some kind, with data that can be read or written to it in blocks. Block devices often represent a mass-storage unit of some kind (for example, a partition on a hard disk or on a USB pen drive).
**Typically they are created in catalog `/dev`**
https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-Linux-block-device

Thus, you should:
1) make sure you created some Linux partition for sftp, for example it will have block device `/dev/sdb10`.
2) build ext4 file system there:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb10
```

3) mount your partiton (if required):

```
sudo mount -v /dev/sdb10 /path/to/MYPJsftpfs
```

4) Check created partition with command `df -h` or `lsblk`.

Comment: thanks for your explained. I already success to create and mount file system but in the same pv.